# How to merge or group an association by another association or rule?

Tags: associations, gathering

I eat the following food over 3 days and track the calories. (Days indexed by `1`,`2`,`3`)

```
caloriesOfFoodEaten =
  {
   1 -> <|"Salmon" -> 500, "Steak" -> 800, "Brocolli" -> 400|>,
   2 -> <|"Salmon" -> 450, "Tuna" -> 800, "Brocolli" -> 800|>,
   3 -> <|"Tuna" -> 600, "Chicken" -> 450, "Steak" -> 700, "Celery" -> 300|>
   };
```

The foods are classified by `"Meat"`, `"Fish"` or `"Vegetable"`

```
mealType = <|"Salmon" -> "Fish", "Steak" -> "Meat", 
   "Brocolli" -> "Vegetable", "Tuna" -> "Fish", "Chicken" -> "Meat", 
   "Celery" -> "Vegetable"|>;
```

How do I efficiently and elegantly get the Total calories eaten by mealType each day?

Desired output:

```
caloriesByMeal =
  {
   1 -> <|"Fish" -> 500, "Meat" -> 800, "Vegetable" -> 400|>,
   2 -> <|"Fish" -> 1250 (* 450 + 800 *), "Vegetable" -> 800|>,
   3 -> <|"Fish" -> 600, "Meat" -> 1150 (* 450 + 700 *), "Vegetable" -> 300|>
   };
```

I have a rather convoluted method with several intermediate steps but I suspect there is an elegant way to use GroupBy or Merge in a few lines

### Edit: TIMINGS

generate large sample

```
caloriesOfFoodEatenLarge =
  Module[
   {days = 100000, numberOfMealsADay, foods, calories},
   SeedRandom[1];
   Table[
    numberOfMealsADay = RandomInteger[Length[mealType]];
    foods = RandomSample[Keys[mealType], numberOfMealsADay];
    calories = RandomInteger[{0, 1000}, numberOfMealsADay];
    day -> AssociationThread[foods, calories],
    {day, days}
    ]
   ];
```

Kuba:

```
Merge[Total]@*KeyValueMap[mealType[#] -> #2 &] /@ <|
    caloriesOfFoodEatenLarge|>; // AbsoluteTiming (* 0.81806 *)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: elegancy is subjective and efficiency was not tested.

```
Merge[Total] @* KeyValueMap[mealType[#] -> #2 &] /@ <|caloriesOfFoodEaten|>
```

Comment: Elegant to my eyes. KeyValueMap was where I had the blind spot!